# Drawing tapered lines programatically in c#

Tags: c#, drawing, line, bezier, curve

is it possible to draw curved tapered lines with c# via code?

i am able to draw curved lines like this:

```
var g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
var p = new Pen(Color.Black);            
var sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);            
PointF[] points = new PointF[] {
    new PointF(1,0),
    new PointF(100,0),
    new PointF(200,100),
    new PointF(400,0),
};
g.DrawBeziers(p,points);
```

but this way i cannot set different widths.

that is what i want to achieve
[image]

Comment: No, there is nothing built-in to produce such an effect. Note that it would need quite a few parameters to define the changing angles. You can create a 2nd bezier and fill a pth but the calculation of good looking coordinates  is not always trivial.. Best make use of graphics rotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was easy once i knew what i had to do:

draw 2 lines and fill the space between:

```
var g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

PointF[] points1 = new PointF[] {
    new PointF(0,0),
    new PointF(100,150),
    new PointF(500,0),
    //new PointF(400,0),
};
PointF[] points2 = new PointF[] {
    new PointF(0,0),
    new PointF(100,160),
    new PointF(500,0),
    //new PointF(400,0),
};

panelPath = new GraphicsPath();
panelPath.AddCurve(points1);
panelPath.AddCurve(points2);
g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, panelPath);
```